# Help with Javascript SQL INSERT

Tags: javascript, sqlite, webos, enyo

I have the following code which inserts a "task" into a table with a value for the "task". I am trying to modify this statement to insert multiple values into multiple columns, but I cant seem to get it to work since I am unfamiliar with the format.

Can sombody show me how the can be modified to insert multiple values?

```
var item  = this.$.newItem.getValue();
this.$.db.query( 'INSERT INTO tasks ( task ) VALUES ( ? )', { values: [ item ] } );
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: What abomination of a javascript library lets you perform datbase inserts?

Comment: This is within HP WebOs Enyo framework, Inserting into a local SQLite DB

Comment: Is this websql?  If not this is the biggest security risk I have ever seen on stackoverflow.

Comment: inserts look like this: INSERT INTO tasks ( task, task_date, remark ) VALUES ( ?,?,? )

Comment: @Jamiec, JavaScript is used for more than just client-side web development. Node.js, for example, is a server-side usage of JavaScript. As a language it's very powerful, but you do have to remember to notify people as to what context it's being called in.

Comment: @zzzBov - im well aware of Javascript's usages, however this looks like it's from a mobile application of some sort. Perhaps this is the defacto way to do database access in webOS. Who knows?

Comment: I can only assume you're referring to the `$`, and assuming that a JS lib like jQuery or prototype is being used. There's nothing in the code that would indicate a client-side usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what this javascript is actually doing makes it hard to answer this question, but suffice it to say the syntax for inserting values into multiple fields in a sql query is as follows

INSERT INTO *tableName* (*col1*, *col2*, *coln*) VALUES (*val1*, *val2*, *valn*)

As a *total* educated guess, I would say you're looking for

```
this.$.db.query( 'INSERT INTO tasks ( task, some_other_field ) VALUES ( ?,? )', { values: [ item, some_other_input ] } );
```

for each "?" in your sql query, you will need another parameter in the `values` array.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you didn't mean to tag this MySQL....

However - a useful class for helping out with Enyo DB queries is:

https://github.com/onecrayon/database-webos

One crayon's implementation. Works very nicely for Enyo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're using some kind of library, but if you're using the standard Web SQL interface to SQLite, the second argument is an *array* of values, not an object like you have.  So code looks more like

```
db.transaction(
    function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(
                "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO contact (contactId, nameG, nameF, orgContactId, accountId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                [contact.contactId, contact.nameG, contact.nameF, contact.orgContactId, contact.accountId],
                function (transaction, resultSet) {   // SQL INSERT statement success
                    // do something now that the item has been saved
                },   // end statement success callback
                function (transaction, sqlError) {   // statement fail
                    // report failed operation
                    return true;   // abort transaction
                }
        );
    }   // end transaction function
    // no transaction callbacks
);   // end transaction call
```